# How to keep weired characters in filename

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, minio

I was creating a website, in which user can upload files on `aws-s3`, `minio` and `azure-storage`, all is working fine,

But when my client upload files with name which contain characters like these,

`AAÀÃÁÆÂÅÄÞC?ÇÈEÉËÊGGIÏÎÍÌLLÑNØÓÒÔÕÖSS?Š?TÙÛÚÜÝZŽZâaaáaãA??åà??A?aäæ?????þcCCcç??c?Cc???dddÐdDddd?d?dðd?????eeeEEeeE?Eê?èëé?fƒf?fggGgGgGg?g?ggggg?g?g?ggg?h?HHh??îïíìiiiI?iiII?I??I???i?j?j?j?jJjjj?j?j?j?j?j?j?j?j?k?kKk?k?kkk?k?l?l?lllllllLlLl?lLlll?l????ñ?N????n?n?Nn??oõôOoOOoø?oò?OoóOœŒö?????qrrRrR?R????Sšs?s?s????ß?t?t?tTt?t?tTtTt™tu?UuUuUUuUuUUuuUUuUùúû?uuUUuuü?v?v?v?wwwWw?yýÿŸY?ž??z?z??~.[]{}()@!#$%^&*+|¦„®©`

or similar to these, these characters become headache, like file uploaded successfully but when fetch it from sources, it is not visible on HTML page, and only broken image shown.

I converted these characters to actual alphabets (example: 'Ĵ'=>'j', 'Ĉ'=>'c', 'ǎ'=>'a') but now my client want to keep these characters as it is, and when user downloaded file, they need same file name as they uploaded,

In backend i am using `PHP` and database is `PostgreSQL`,

How can i solve this issue.

Comment: Those are "actual alphabets", they're just not part of the 7-bit ASCII (Roman, mostly) character set. Time to learn about text encodings and unicode!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use these characters in the name of the blob. See [this article about naming and referencing blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata). What you might try is storing the original name in the [metadata] property after uploading the blob, and retrieving it when you download or refer to the blob.